# Spring Integration - Message Store configuration for Microsoft SQL Server 2012

Tags: java, sql-server, spring, sql-server-2012, spring-integration

I setup a MessageStore in Spring Integration using JDBC, following there's my configuration:

```
<bean id="queryProvider" class="org.springframework.integration.jdbc.store.channel.MySqlChannelMessageStoreQueryProvider" />

<!-- JDBC message store configuration -->
<bean id="store" class="org.springframework.integration.jdbc.store.JdbcChannelMessageStore">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="basicDataSource" />
    <property name="channelMessageStoreQueryProvider" ref="queryProvider" />
    <property name="region" value="TX_TIMEOUT" />
    <property name="usingIdCache" value="true" />
</bean>
```

My underlying DB is Microsoft SQL Server 2012 and when starting up the server I get the following exception:

```
nested exception is com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Incorrect syntax near 'LIMIT'.
at org.springframework.jdbc.support.AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.translate(AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.java:83)
at org.springframework.jdbc.support.AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.translate(AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.java:80)
at org.springframework.jdbc.support.AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.translate(AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.java:80)
at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.execute(JdbcTemplate.java:605)
at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.query(JdbcTemplate.java:639)
at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.query(JdbcTemplate.java:664)
at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.query(JdbcTemplate.java:704)
```

How can I fix this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way to implement `SqlServerChannelMessageStoreQueryProvider` and don't use `MySqlChannelMessageStoreQueryProvider`, because those RDBMS vendors use different DML.

Feel free to raise a [JIRA](https://jira.spring.io/browse/INT) ticket and even [contribute](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration/blob/master/CONTRIBUTING.md)!

Comment: Thanks, Artem. I'll do it.